# Consulta por propiedad de un combobox en c# con visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un formulario, en el tengo un campo de texto y un combobox. Al cargar el form se hace una consulta a una base de datos y en el combobox se cargan unas descripciones. Si yo selecciono una el id de la descripción me aparece en el textbox.

Quiero hacer lo contrario, que yo al escribir en el textboox y dar enter me aparezca la descripción que le corresponde, voy a poner los codigos:

#### Form4_Load

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = conexion;

    com.CommandText = "select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc order by Descripcion";

    SqlDataReader rea = com.ExecuteReader();

    while (rea.Read())
    {
        cmbbox_documento.Items.Add(rea[1]);
    }
    CerrarConexion(); 
}
```

#### SelectedValueChanged

```
private void cmbbox_documento_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand cdo = new SqlCommand();
    cdo.Connection = conexion;
    string descrip = cmbbox_documento.SelectedItem.ToString();

    cdo.CommandText = "select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc where Descripcion='" + descrip + "'";

    SqlDataReader reader = cdo.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txt_documento.Text = reader[0].ToString();
    }
    CerrarConexion();
}
```

Y ahora como creo que tendría que ser para que me capture el dato del textbox cuando le doy enter:

```
private void txt_documento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        string var = txt_documento.Text.ToString();

        if (var != "" || var !=" ")
        {
            AbrirConexion();
            SqlCommand cdo = new SqlCommand();
            cdo.Connection = conexion;

            cdo.CommandText = "select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc where Codigo='" + var + "'";

            SqlDataReader reader = cdo.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cmbbox_documento.SelectedValue = reader[0].ToString();
            }
            CerrarConexion();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Está bien la propiedad **SelectedValue**? Probé con **SelectedItem** o **SelectedText** pero no me trae el valor como creo que debería ser.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada como en un caso almacenas Descripciones y luego a partir de un codigo necesitas seleccionar una descripcion te recomiendo que almacenes en los items del combobox una estructura que contenga ambos datos por ejemplo:

```
struct Dato
{
    public string Codigo;
    public string Descripcion;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Descripcion;
    }
}
```

A la hora de almacenar tus Descripciones harias lo siguiente (en el while de tu `Form_Load`):

```
cmbbox_documento.Items.Add(new Dato(){ Codigo = rea[0].toString(), Descripcion = rea[1].ToString()});
```

En el `SelectedValueChanged` cambiaria el codigo de asignacion al texto a buscar por:

```
string descrip = ((Dato)cmbbox_documento.SelectedItem).Descripcion.ToString();
```

Y en el KeyPress kedaria como esto:

```
cmbbox_documento.SelectedItem = new Dato(){ Codigo = reader[0].ToString(), Descripcion = reader[1].ToString()};
```

Espero que puedas resolver con esto cualquier duda me avisas ;P

Comment: Hola, buenos días. Con el código que va en el KeyPress tengo una duda, esa línea vendría a reemplazar lo que yo tengo? porque (poniendo tu linea) cuando ejecuto el código y pongo un punto de control para revisar, en tu linea me salta un error **Sistem.InvalidOperationException: No está autorizado a cambiar la propiedad ConnectionString**. Revisé mis variables de conexion y están bien, probé con la línea que tengo yo y también corre bien, así que es tu linea jajaja. ¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: Primero que nada es como lo comentastes debes reemplazar tu linea dentro del `while`, lo que no entiendo es que tiene que ver lo mio con cambiar el ConnectionString si puedes ponme como quedo tu codigo con esta modificacion

Comment: hola, si yo igual te entiendo, no tiene nada que ver una cosa con la otra pero como te digo me salta el error, te dejo link para que veas la función [link](https://gist.github.com/dmp3kl/c98362c20665eeea00fa36aca0fbc076)

Comment: Me surgen dos dudas donde declarastes `Dato` y si reemplazas el valor de Codigo y Descripcion por cadenas vacias te sigue dando el mismo error? Lo otro que puedes hacer es intentar mostrar el reader[0] y el reader[1] y probar que no salte el error

Comment: la estructura de Dato la declaré al comienzo, dentro de *public partial class Form4 : Form{} *. Si reemplazo las cadenas de Código y Descripción como tú dices no pasa nada, y si pongo dentro del *while* -> **MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());** me muestra bien los datos

Comment: te dejo el código completo en [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/axwVKR). No entiendo por qué se cae si las funciones de AbrirConexion y CerrarConexion están bien puestas. Lo otro que estaba pensando es publicar esta duda como una nueva pregunta